# Send emails with up to a maximum number of addresses per email

Tags: vba, loops, email, outlook

I found Excel VBA code and it works.  However, due to Outlook's maximum of 500 addresses per email, I need to create a loop and count the instances.

The primary data columns.
Column B - email address
Column F - "x" (lowercase to indicate an email must be sent)

The "x"s that appear in Column F require the counting and the loop. There will be 2,500-3,000 "ticked" in column F, so that would generate 6 emails with the loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

' Change to path of OFT Template (AND user name)
    Set OutEmail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Change Notification.oft")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value) = "x" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .SentOnBehalfOfName = "shared@abccorp.com"
                .to = cell.Value
                .Send  'Or use Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value in column F. `Exit For` at the max.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Dim sentCount As Long
    Dim sendLimit As Long
    
    sentCount = 0
    sendLimit = 3   ' 500
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
          LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value) = "x" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            
            With OutMail
                .SentOnBehalfOfName = "shared@abccorp.com"
                .to = cell.Value
                .Display 'Or .Send
                
                Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value = "Sent"
                sentCount = sentCount + 1
            End With
            
            Set OutMail = Nothing
            
            ' Generally less risk than an =
            If sentCount > sendLimit - 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Debug.Print sentCount & " emails created."
End Sub
```

[VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#On_Error_Resume_Next)

Comment: I tried and that doesn't work right. I mean it does work, but with separate email for each name, and no template.  I would like it to be 1 email with 500 names (Outlook max), then a new email would be generated for the next 500 names.  So if there happen to be 2,500 names listed, only 5 emails would be generated, each with 500 names.  Also, in the VBA code I provided, I included (under the variables) a line of code that accesses an OFT template in Outlook that is to be used.  That was not there in this code.  And when I tried to add it back, my lack of VBA knowledge showed!  LOL

Answer (score 0):

This limits the number of addresses in a mail.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub LimitAddresses()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Dim addressCount As Long
    Dim addressLimit As Long
    
    addressLimit = 3  ' Testing with a reasonable sample size
    'addressLimit = 500
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Not in alpha test
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Change Notification.oft")
    
    addressCount = 0
    
    'On Error GoTo cleanupError ' Not in alpha test
    
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
          LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value) = "x" Then
            
            With OutMail
                .to = .to & ";" & cell.Value
                'Debug.Print .to
                addressCount = addressCount + 1
                
                ' Indicate address processed
                ' Not necessary
                ' Could reduce duplicate mail when there is an error
                Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value = "In .To"  
            End With
            
            If addressCount > addressLimit - 1 Then
                OutMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "shared@abccorp.com"
                OutMail.Display 'Or .Send
                Set OutMail = Nothing
                
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Change Notification.oft")
                
                addressCount = 0
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next cell

    If Not OutMail Is Nothing Then OutMail.Display 'Or .Send

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Debug.Print " Done."
    Exit Sub
    
cleanupError:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume cleanup
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This did not quite work.  The macro only added the first 3 email addresses to my email template.  And the original "X" to in dictate an email needs to be sent was replaced by "In.To".  In this specific instance, there were a total of 3,853 names on this list that needed an email.  That should have been 3,853/500 - 7.706, so 8 emails should have been generated for this list.  I do not understand why it did not work right;  I did not get any "spinnies", not responding messages, or any other errors.  It did tell me that 3 recipients were outside the organization.

Comment: Change addressLimit from 3 to 500

Comment: The "In .To" or whatever you want indicates "already processed".

Comment: You cannot see VBA error messages when you indicate you want to bypass errors with `On Error GoTo cleanup`.